# How does the Dual Enchanting Perk work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I get the Dual Enchanting Perk, can I add an additional enchantment to an item that I previously? Similarly, can I add an extra enchantment to an item that  ***I***  didn't enchant, but found already enchanted?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No and No.

The **Extra Effect** perk only works for newly enchanted items, and both enchantments must be applied at once. You cannot enchant an item that is already enchanted.

You can, however, disenchant an item to learn that effect, and then apply it, along with an additional one to a new item of your choosing. Seeing as you'll have a 100 Enchanting Skill at this point, the item you create is almost certainly going to be better than the one you've destroyed to learn the effect anyway.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all enchantments found on items ingame can be learned.

Comment: @bkzland And some that CAN be learned, can't be used. (Shadowstrike, Shadowthrive, etc.)

Comment: I noticed that the first enchantment is full strength but when you add a second enchantment the strength is diluted.

Comment: @M.TravisVolker This is untrue. I've tested it pretty heavily, and have never experienced that. There are however, some UI bugs regarding displayed enchantment strength before you select a soul gem.